# Xubuntu touchpad slows down (delayed) when i plug my earphones

Tags: pulseaudio

title says it all. i think it has to do with pulse audio. please help. thanks :D

Comment: What is the model of your touchpad?

Comment: What model is your computer? If it's sufficiently slow then you may have display lag/jittering.

Comment: my laptop is samsung ativ book 9 lite. i don't think it is too weak to run xfce.

Comment: i run glxgears while i plug in and out my earphones. it is a constant 60 fps.

Comment: android dev, i cant seem to find how to view the specific model of my touchpad. but the brand is elantech, if that helps.